# NGINX won't start (mkdir failed)

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with NGINX.

The process die with message :

nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "~/bin/nginx/client_body_temp" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Any way to investigate ?

Nginx version : nginx/1.21.6
OS : Debian GNU/Linux 10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix Nginx: [emerg] mkdir() “/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body” failed (2: No such file or directory) error just create a new directory using mkdir command:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp/
```

Finally, try to test and restart/start nginx:

```
nginx -t
/etc/init.d/nginx start
```

A note about Docker Nginx users
Docker users should add the following RUN in their Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp/
```

Note : Use sudo in front of every command if you are not a root user.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essence in your answer, otherwise the answer becomes useless when that link dies.

Comment: The folder creation seems to work the first time, but then the problem is located in the file nginx.conf.

But, before all this I had "dlopen" problem (I had to delete all symlinks in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled).

I didn't changed anything (maybe an update ?) and the problem is moving from a file to another.

Now the result is :
nginx: the configuration file nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "~/bin/nginx/client_body_temp" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file nginx.conf test failed

Note there is no Docker.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).